# Local maximum of $(2^{xy}{z \choose y})^{z+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, extremal-combinatorics

I have an optimization problem where I need to calculate the maximum of the following function
$$
f(x,y,z) = (2^{xy}{z \choose y})^{z+1}
$$
where
$$
(z+1)(a+y(\lceil{\log_2{(z+1)}}\rceil+x))\leq C
$$

$a,C$ are constants.

$a,x,y,z$ are all positive integers.

Using approximations is allowed. Just need to get close.

I have had mathematical analysis courses, but this is beyond me. 
Would be great if somebody showed their work or walked me through the process. I'm here to learn.

Comment: What is the domain of definition of $f$? Are $z$ and $y$ natural numbers (they seem so, given that they appear in a binomial coefficient)?

Comment: The domain is $\mathbb{R}$ and $z, y$ are natural numbers, but if you have a solution where $z, y$ are positive real numbers, it would be as helpful.

Comment: I wouldn't know what $\binom z y$ could mean for real numbers (some sort of Beta function?).

Comment: Wolframalpha gave me alternative using the $\Gamma$ function http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=combination(z,y)

Comment: Yes, and that can be further written as $\dfrac 1 {y \ B(y, -y + z + 1)}$. Anyway, your problem is so ugly that I doubt that it can be approached. Do you want an approximate maximum, or just an uppper bound (the latter might be easier to compute, but very rough and far from the maximum)?

Comment: approximate maximum would be more useful